# Registration Form in Keycloak where some data is forwarded to RemoteEJB, is this possible?

Tags: registration, ejb-3.1, keycloak

I am planing a registration form, where some data is stored in keycloak. Other data should be saved by a remote ejb. I am thinking of doing this in keycloak, is this possible? And what might be the cleanest way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather recommend to implement the custom registration form in a separate application and then propagate the relevant data to Keycloak utilizing its public REST API ([Keycloak REST API for user management](http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.3/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)).

Comment: Yeah, that would be the alternative solution. Thanx for your answer, but my customer insists to go through the keycloak way, and I will create a customized solution with freemarker.Either way, i accept your answer.